# How to access the parent collection in a each closure?

Tags: ruby, closures

I'm looking from something that to replace the `*parent*`.

```
%w[apple apples].each do |w|
   next if *parent*.includes? w + "s"
   puts w
end

# output: apples
```

Comment: you could try a different enumerable function than each, find_all would work well for you here: `%w(apple apples).find_all{|fruit| fruit if fruit.match(/s$/)}`

Comment: @Jed: That doesn't do the same thing. (Also the `fruit if` part is unnecessary)

Comment: @sepp2k, sorry forgot 'puts' in the block which is why you would need the postfix if,( `...find_all{|fruit| puts fruit if fruit.match(/s$/)}`

Comment: @Jed: But then the result of `find_all` will just be the empty array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each` is a convention, there is no concept of a "parent collection" for blocks in general or ones passed to each in particular. Just name it, eg

```
(parent = %w[apple apples]).each do |w|
  next if parent.includes? w + "s"
  puts w
end
```

You could add a different method to pass a parent,

eg

```
module Each2
 def each2
   each { |elem| yield(self, elem) }
 end
end

include Each2

%w[apple apples].each2 do |parent, w|
  next if parent.includes? w + "s"
  puts w
end
```

But this is pretty silly.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do that. You'll have to give the collection a name first:

```
fruits = %w[apple apples]
fruits.each do |w|
   next if fruits.includes? w + "s"
   puts w
end
```

Comment: `Object#tap` (v1.9+) may effectively name the collection, but it does restrict the scope of the variable: `%w[apple apples].tap { |f| f.each { |w| puts w unless f.include? w + "s" } }`.