# Accessing the Object I'm calling "select" on from within the block

Tags: ruby

This would be an example of a structure that hopefully helps illustrate the point. Although please *note that my objective is **not** to accomplish the specific logic of **this** example*, but rather to find out how to access that Object in this context.

```rb
'0234'.split('').each_index do |i|
  puts 'self'[i] # <- Here
end
```

At "Here" level I would like to replace `'self'` with the result of the operation `'0234'.split('')`, I thought `self` would do, but via debugging I found that `self = main`.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `select`?

Comment: your code example, no way fits with the method `select`s usecase..

Comment: Yes, updated question! Why downvotes without explanation?

Comment: Why code without explanation?

Comment: The final objective might be a bit more complicated than what the code shows(simply `puts char`). But the question `Accessing the Object you call **select** on from within the block` is, at least to my eyes, pretty **clear**. If you disagree, you can just say it and I will edit it to detail it more, just downvoting is not very constructive.

Comment: vint-i-vuit, I sympathize with your request for explanations for the downvotes, but when there are any--and certainly when there is more than one, you can generally figure out the problem from the comments.  Here you should not explain what you want to do by referencing your code.  Say it in words, being precise, succinct and complete, and add sample inpu and output when helpful.  Here your sample input is `st = 0234`.  What do you want the method to print and/or return?  Don't say it is obvious. It is not.  I suggest you edit your question (post-votes!) to avoid additional downvotes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: thank you for the helpful comment, I appreciate it. I did edit the question adding notes post-votes, to try to make clear that my goal wasn't the specific code logic, but accessing the "parent" variable from within the `block` context. I will try to edit the content of the question to emphasize this, although I think the title of the question is quite specific and complete, would you have a change suggestion? Thanks once more.

Comment: @vint-i-vuit, is your objective to have a variable referring to the receiver available within the block? If so, please just detail the specific problem you're trying to solve. Including random code isn't likely to yield a satisfactory answer.

Comment: 'post-votes' in my comment was intended to be 'post-haste', but I was overruled by software.

Comment: @ZachKemp: That's exactly what I want! Ok, so I think I will just start over with a new question. I thought that including random *example* code would actually help providing the context, considering that I emphasized that the objective is not to resolve the example code itself. Very helpful comment!

Comment: Would the use of [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) (v 1.9+) meet your requirement? `'0234'.split('').tap { |a| a.each_index { |i| puts a[i] } }` prints `0`, `2`, `3` and `4`, and returns `["0","2","3","4"]`.

Comment: that's an interesting workaround, it gets closer, thanks! I guess there is no way to do *exactly* what I intended to do. As can be seen also in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695789/how-to-access-the-parent-collection-in-a-each-closure

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may prefer `'0234'.split('').tap { |a| ... }` to `(a = '0234'.split(''))...`, as `tap` restricts the scope of the local variable `a` to its block.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use index at all:

```
st='0234'
st.each_char do |chr|
  puts chr
end
```

Regarding comment:

```
st='0234'
st.each_char.with_index do |chr, idx|
  puts idx
  puts chr
end
```

Comment: Well, I don't really want to `puts chr`, I simplified the problem in order to focus on the point. I actually will want the indexes.

Comment: Updated answer, if you want to access st, you don't need to use self, st is in the scope in the each block

Comment: Please put your requirements in the question from the start next time.

Comment: The title of the question didn't change, and it's the exact thing I want to know! Is that the point of the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I sense a level of frustration that there is something fairly basic that you feel you are missing. Let's start by going back to your original code and see what's going on.  You had:

```
  st = '0234'
  a  = st.split('') # ["0", "2", "3", "4"] 
  a.each_index.select do |i|
    puts a[i]
  end
```

Try this:

```
a.each_index      #=> <Enumerator:["0","2","3","4"]:each_index>
a.each_index.to_a #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
a.each_index { |i| puts i } #=> ["0","2","3","4"]
```

where `=>` signifies the return value. The following four lines are printed by the last statement:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Compare that with this:

```
b = %w{I love chocolate cake} #=> ["I","love","chocolate","cake"]

b.each_index #=> <Enumerator:["I","love","chocolate","cake"]:each_index>
b.each_index.to_a #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
b.each_index { |i| puts i } #=> ["I","love","chocolate","cake"]
```

The same four lines are printed by the last statement:

```
0
1 
2
3
```

See what is happening?  In both cases, the enumerator is passing the indices of the elements of `a` and `b` (not the elements) to the block.

Now consider the following:

```
a.each_index.select { |i| i > 1 } #=> [2,3]
b.each_index.select { |i| i > 1 } #=> [2,3]
```

Both of these `select` the indices `i` for which the expression in the block (`i > 1`) evaluates to `true`.

Lastly, compare this with:

```
a.each_with_index      #=> <Enumerator:["0","2","3","4"]:each_with_index>
a.each_with_index.to_a #=> [["0",0], ["2",1], ["3",2], ["4",3]]

b.each_with_index
  #=> <Enumerator:["I","love","chocolate","cake"]:each_with_index>
b.each_with_index.to_a #=> [["I",0],["love",1],["chocolate",2],["cake",3]]

a.each_with_index.select { |e,i| i > 1 } #=> [[3,2],[4,3]]
b.each_with_index.select { |e,i| i > 1 } #=> [["chocolate",2],["cake",3]]
```

I hope this helps.  Do not hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated comment! What I would like to do is to access `a` or `b`(i.e. a variable referring to the receiver of the method)from within the block, but without using the variables `a` nor `b`. I.e.` %w{I love chocolate cake}.each_with_index.select{|e,i| #Access %w{I love...} here }`. I believe ZachKemp's explained it very clearly in the comments.